# gcc: fixing -pedantic "unnamed structure" warning

Tags: c, gcc, struct, compiler-warnings, gcc-pedantic

I'm trying to get some code from elsewhere (specifically, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8255487/1020588)), to compile without any warnings when gcc is given the `-pedantic` flag.  The only problem is this bit of code:

```
struct __attribute__ ((aligned(NLMSG_ALIGNTO))) {
    struct nlmsghdr nl_hdr;
    /* Unnamed struct start. */
    struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) {
        struct cn_msg cn_msg;
        struct proc_event proc_ev;
    };
    /* Unnamed struct end. */
} nlcn_msg;
```

No matter where I try to put in a name for the structure, it results in a compilation error.  Is there some way to modify the given code to satisfy `-pedantic`?  Or is there some way to tell gcc to not issues a warning just for that piece of code?

Comment: Saw this in [an answer to an SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/133521/434551). `#pragma warning (disable : 4068 )`. Perhaps something similar just before the function might work.

Comment: `#pragma warning (disable : 4068 )` doesn't seem to work with gcc

Comment: A different warning number, one that represents the warning you are trying to stop from being displayed, should work.

Comment: No, I tried multiple  numbers, and they all gave the same warning message about ignoring it.

Comment: what is the actual, complete, warning messge?

Comment: `warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]`

Comment: Why do you want to use `-pedantic`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which standard are you compiling to?

Given this code:

```
#define NLMSG_ALIGNTO 4

struct nlmsghdr { int x; };
struct cn_msg { int x; };
struct proc_event { int x; };

struct __attribute__ ((aligned(NLMSG_ALIGNTO))) {
    struct nlmsghdr nl_hdr;
    /* Unnamed struct start. */
    struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) {
        struct cn_msg cn_msg;
        struct proc_event proc_ev;
    };
    /* Unnamed struct end. */
} nlcn_msg;
```

Compiling with C99 mode, I get errors:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition -Werror -pedantic -c x2.c
x2.c:13:6: error: ISO C99 doesn’t support unnamed structs/unions [-Werror=pedantic]
     };
      ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$
```

Compiling with C11 mode, I get no errors:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
      -Wold-style-definition -Werror -pedantic -c x2.c
$
```

Comment: Using `-std=c11` fixes the problem I wrote of, but introduces the problem that it now gives `implicit declaration of function ‘siginterrupt’` even though I'm including `signal.h`.

Comment: Then change it to `-std=gnu11`…that allows most other declarations to be created when the `c11` variant doesn't.